# Genymotion slow down my computer

Tags: android

the ova file folder is not present in genymobile=genymotion.

how i can add virtual device offline i mean add manually

i tried much but all in vein.

the folder ova is not currently present in the location is

program>files>genymobile>genymotion.then there is no ova folder to copy the ova

file there.

i use window 8.i changed the window

i reinstall all of these

but not found the ova folder

and sometime i download the virtual device directly by genymotion

so then my system become hang mean become so slow and does not work properly

i have 2 gb ram and 500gb hardisk and 2.0glu etc